# Send ESC (ASCII 27) to sensor using putty

Tags: putty, serial, sensors

I am working on the Young anemometer 81000, datasheet: http://www.youngusa.com/Manuals/81000-90(I).pdf.

Section 4.0 COMMAND MENU tells me I should send the ESC character (ASCII 27) 3 times in quick succession, but I don't know how.

What I have tried:

- press three times on ESC key on my keyboard.
- press ctrl-$ three times on my keyboard

It feels like I don't understand how to actually send the ESC char.

Small note: the datasheet tells me I should get wind speed measurements (page 2 left upper corner), but as of now I get something like this:

▒▒▒v▒f~~▒▒gf▒[▒F4▒▒▒▒g▒&▒▒▒<▒▒▒f▒▒▒▒▒▒v▒~>V?T▒▒▒fT&▒
▒▒▒v▒▒P▒▒v>▒▒▒gSv▒@▒▒▒v▒&▒▒▒f>▒▒igS▒▒▒▒▒gv▒
▒▒V<▒▒[Sv>
▒▒▒▒▒f▒&▒▒
▒f@▒▒S▒6▒}▒▒▒f▒▒▒▒▒▒v▒▒▒Sv>gy▒▒▒f▒&▒▒▒▒f▒▒▒▒fv▒▒▒▒▒f>2~~~>F>>T▒sf▒gyPP▒

I am using the correct baud-rate of 38400, so this is not a cause of issues normally.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I was trying to read a RS232 (which is a higher voltage than 5V) with a arduino which uses TTL voltages (5V or 3.3 V)

So the solution to the problem was simply buying a RS232 to TTL converter